# Closing popup while clicking any other place in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a readonly TextBox in WPF and i have opened the Popup in TextBox MouseDown event( Popup.IsOpen set as true as well as StaysOpen of a Popup set as false). Now i am able to open the popup by down the mouse in TextBox. Now if I click any other place in the window means ( other than the TextBox, Popup), the popup is not closed. Is the behavior of pop-up?

Comment: are you showing more than one popup at a time?

Comment: no, i am showing one pop-up at a time.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not a normal behavior of the `Popup` control if you have `StaysOpen` set to `false`. The normal behavior is described in the documentation as:

> **Popup.StaysOpen Property**
>
> > Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the Popup control closes when the control is no longer in focus.

With that being said, it's hard for us to tell what exactly is happening in your program if you don't show us any code, so that we may reproduce said behavior.  As an example, here's a sample application which has a `Popup` control open when it starts and as soon as you click anywhere else, the `Popup` will disappear:

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Popup IsOpen="True" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Center"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
            <Grid Background="RoyalBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="Popup Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="White"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is the expected behavior of the popup.
Unless you call the function window.close(), the popup will not be closed.

If you are using a MessageBox, then you can call the close function during click of a button or so.

If you are using a window, then you can call the window.close() on any of the action triggers by the user, such as a button click, or automatically timeout after a few seconds or so. Hope this clears your doubt.